# tomcat6 configuration on centos5: tomcat ignores values in /etc/sysconfig/tomcat6

Tags: centos5, tomcat6

I make changes in `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat6`, in the `init.d` script the global values in `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf` are set, and then ovridden by anything I set in `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat6`.  However, the `init.d` script calls `/usr/bin/dtomcat` as the last step, this script again reads the global file, thus obliterating any changes I made in `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat6`

I don't want to edit `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf`, I'd like to have multiple instances running.  Can someone enlighten me? Do most people just edit the global file?

Comment: Multiple Tomcat-instances or multiple deployed instances of the same application? If the former - why?

Comment: multiple tomcat instances, some of the apps have duplicate context names as well as having a desire to restart one container while leaving the others up.

Comment: That is even one more reason to stick to the tgz solution. With the CentOS solution the installation was pretty bound to one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people propably do the same with tomcat6 as with tomcat5:

1. Throw away the packages delivered with CentOS
2. Download tgz from apache-tomcat.
3. Create directory of your choice
4. Untar there
5. configure
6. run

I tried to get tomcat5 running on CentOS5 and gave up - reverting to 1 through 6 gave me a running tomcat in no time.

Comment: Yeah. that'd work as my issue is largely with the startup scripts provided with the CentOS rpm.  However these machines are all in the cloud, it's so much easier to stick with the rpms to have these guys spun up quickly in large numbers.

Comment: You could try to build a relocatable rpm with the tgz. That way you just have to provide one additional parameter and install many instances in many places. As for the startup-scripts - what about the ones provided with Apache-Tomcat6? Are they still as bad as with Tomcat5?